# How to insert date in to the copy Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to three tables (**stock**,**trans** and **sales**). I copy the stock Table into the trans using

```
insert into trans (idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price)select idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price from stock WHERE idProduct = '" + id + "'
```

And also copy table values to trans to sales using

```
insert into sales(idProduct,product_name,Product_size,qty,product_price) select idProduct,product_name,Product_size,qty,product_price from trans
```

Now I want to insert the current date in to the trans table particular row's cell.

how????

Comment: What if you create a new column named 'date' which has to be timestamp with default_value current timestamp? This one will fill with the current date of the insert.

Comment: use Curdate()  or Now()

Comment: correction I have three tables....

Comment: @Grommy thanks... but i want just date.... no time

Comment: So just change the timestamp type that I have said, with date type. And it will work pretty nice ;)

Comment: @MuhammadKashif grommy is right , and believe me timestamp is one of the best option to use. there are 100's of option available for timestamp manipulations. And ofcourse , sql and php both know how to deal with it. and anyways you can extract date with simple functions available in php. I use timestamp , everyone in here use timestamp.

Comment: @Grommy ,Smita ,Nirpendra Thanks to all for help me.... problem solved .....

Comment: I posted you a new solution more efficiently than which you have got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NOW()` and doing it in the first insert.

```
insert into trans (idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price,particular_col)
select idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price,now() 
from stock WHERE idProduct = '" + id + "'
```

I've add to the list of column `particular_column` , place it in the right place with it right name, same goes for `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same work more efficiently. Assign to you column date, the default value as a current_timestamp (in the table). Then, you can forgot the mysql command NOW() in the query:

```
insert into trans (idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price)
select idProduct,product_name,product_size,product_qty,details,product_price
from stock WHERE idProduct = '" + id + "'
```

:-)